# How to save prefs to different scopes in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, preferences, shared

I am trying to use shared prefs to store App Data and User Data differently, like this :

```
{
    "APP_DATA": {
        "banners": "{\"success\":true,\"data\":{}}",
        "gameList": "{\"success\":true,\"data\":{}}"
    },
    "USER_DATA": 
      {
          "emailVerified": "N",
          "userName": "97144554455",
          "playerToken": "W_8zUx3UCmFPeECjhhjhHhnnsajknHxAM0",
          "idVerified": "UPLOADED",
          "playerId": "412904",
          "bankList": "{\"84\":\"African Bank\",\"5\":\"FNB : First National Bank\"}",
          "unreadMsgCount": "0"
      }
}
```

But whenever I update any value in "APP_DATA" or "USER_DATA", it deletes the previous value and updates new value. Example : After adding "banners" and "gamesList" to my  APP_DATA, I only see "gamesList" because it is overriding the "banners" value.

```
  MySharedPreferences.instance.setAppStringValue(
    "banners", jsonEncode(bannersModel),
  );

  MySharedPreferences.instance.setAppStringValue(
    "gamesList", jsonEncode(gamesListModel),
  );
```

This is the function I'm using

```
  setAppStringValue(String key, String value) async {
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    myPrefs.setString("APP_DATA", jsonEncode({key: value}));
  }
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that you are overriding the `APP_DATA` key with a whole new value (encoded `String`) which results in the previous data to be lost.

If you want to keep the same structure, this is, having a key for `APP_DATA` and other for `USER_DATA`, both having their own data, you'll need to fetch the previous stored data and append the new one into it so you make sure you don't lose it.

```
 setAppStringValue(String key, String value) async {
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final String storedData = myPrefs.get('APP_DATA');
    final Map newData = {key: value};

    try {
      // Has previous data, decode it and append into the new one
      if (storedData != null) {
        newData.addAll(jsonDecode(storedData));
      }
    } catch (ex) {
      print('Couldn\'t parse the stored data: $ex');
    }

    myPrefs.setString('APP_DATA', jsonEncode(newData));
  }
```

Comment: Yup! This worked. I was a simple solution, but I was not able to think of it. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

When using shared preferences, it uses the unique key to recognise the value of the corresponding data. When you are writing data to the key 'APP_DATA' it will overwrite the entire string value. To change one value without overwriting the rest, you should save it in different keys. Like so,

```
 setAppStringValue(String key, String value) async {
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    myPrefs.setString("banner", jsonEncode({key: value}));
  }

 setAppStringValue(String key, String value) async {
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    myPrefs.setString("gamesList", jsonEncode({key: value}));
  }
```

Comment: But when user is logging out, I only want to clear `USER_DATA`. not `APP_DATA` that's why I am trying to store it in different keys.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. Split APP_DATA into two keys. Also please dont downvote answers, instead mention the entire issue in the question.

Comment: I am not downvoting the answer..